# Formato de fecha DD-MM-YYYY muestra fecha actual si no ingreso nada

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Resulta que inserto la fecha en la base con el campo

```
input name="fecha1" type="date"
input name="fecha2" type="date"
input name="fecha3" type="date"
```

se inserta bien la fecha con el formato: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Cuando hago un `SELECT` modifico la fecha así:

```
echo date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($crow['fechaa1']));
echo date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($crow['fechaa2']));
echo date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($crow['fechaa3']));
```

Se muestra bien: `d/mm/yyyy`, pero resulta que si la persona no ingresó ninguna fecha, se muestra la fecha del día, y en verdad no debería mostrar nada, porque no son campos obligatorios.

Sin embargo si dejo el formato sin cambios `YYYY-MM-DD`, se muestra solo los campos que se agregó la fecha y en los otros campos no se muestra nada, pero si cambio de formato sí, si la persona no ingresó ninguna fecha muestra la fecha del día.

No sé cómo resolver eso.

aclarando a todos que: la base esta bien, el problema solo ocurre cuando yo modifico la fecha, si traigo asi como la guardo no hay problema.
por ejemplo: en el formulario hay tres fecha:
ingrese fecha de entrada:
ingrese fecha de salida: (no es obligatoria)
cuando traigo de la base de datos asi viene:
fecha de entrada: 2020-6-10
fecha de salida: (en blanco)
ahora se yo formateo la fecha asi: echo date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($crow['fechaa3']));
me muestra:
fecha de entrada: 10/6/2020
fecha de salida: 10/6/2020
se entiende??

Comment: SIn mayúscula sostenida, por favor

Comment: los imputs que value tienen por defecto???

Comment: Ninguno <input name="fecha1" type="date" class="form-control input-lg"   placeholder="Fecha:" />, lo traro es que en la base de datos mysql si la persona lo ingreso fecha no carga nada

Comment: y si añades value="" que te guarda??? prueba a ver...

Comment: Debe ser algo sencillo, pero es que ni siquiera se llega a entender cuál es el problema ni dónde es el problema. Por ejemplo, ¿qué es `$crow` exactamente? Si en esa variable intentas una fecha que no haya sido rellenada, lo primero es que vas a tener un *`Undefined index`*  y lo segundo es que el `echo` te imprimirá cualquier cosa, sea la fecha de hoy, sea la fecha del 1 de enero de 1970 o lo que sea, según el contexto. Tu tarea aquí como programador es controlar el código, de modo que nunca se llegue a intentar imprimir algo que no existe. ¿De qué modo estás controlando eso?

Comment: se le agrego el value="" pasa lo mismo, el problema es que si la persona no ingreso ninguna fecha me muestra la fecha del día actual, y, si yo formateo no formateo la fecha no me muestra nada como debería ser, el problema está en el formateo de la fecha, solo cuando pongo print date('d/m/Y', strtotime($crow['fecha1'])) es que me muestra la fecha actual si la persona no ingreso ninguna fecha. Gracias

Comment: el usuario puede usar la fecha actual como validad o tiene que ser una fecha pasada o futura??? yo tengo ese tipo de control y cuando la fecha es igual a hoy guardo el valor como null en la base de datos XD

Comment: ¿Qué es `$crow`? Si no explicas el contexto es difícil poder ayudarte. En la pregunta no se entiende siquiera si el problema está cuando obtienes la fecha de la base de datos o cuando la obtienes de un campo del formulario. En todo caso, el *quid* de la cuestión aquí es **¿por qué se intenta imprimir un contenido que está en blanco o no existe?** Como programador tú debes validar los elementos antes de insertarlos, imprimirlos, modificarlos, etc. Y parte de esa validación es comprobar que no son nulos o en blanco.

Comment: aclarando que el $crow viene de la la consulta a la base:
$base = "SELECT * FROM novedad N JOIN empleados E ON  N.id_empleado=E.id_empleado WHERE id='$id'";
 $nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
 $crow = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery);
y en la base inserta lo que la persona ingreso, si no ingreso nada no se inserta nada, por lo tanto no se muestra nada. El problema esta cuando cambio el formato la fecha

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta tooooooooodas las veces necesarias para añadir aclaraciones y código que falte. Mira cómo en los comentarios el código es difícil de seguir; ponlo en la pregunta. Las aclaraciones también van allá arriba en la pregunta :)

Comment: No me queda ninguna duda de que el gran problema aquí es de diseño y de lógica... Lo señalo para que lo consideres más adelante. De todos modos, para centrarnos en el problema concreto, ¿si haces un `var_dump($crow);` qué muestra? Según he entendido, en la base de datos se guardaron fechas vacías (quizá eso no debió suceder y para evitarlo habrá que rediseñar las tablas, o tu BD puede ser un cúmulo de nulos, pero bueno, ese es otro asunto). Pues si hay fechas vacías, controla que no sean traídas en el SELECT o controla antes de imprimirlas, o sea verifica que no estén vacías antes de imprimir.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos ya pude resolver, descubrí que la fecha que me trae por defecto el campo date es: `01/01/1970` entonces le hice un if:

```
if(date('d/m/Y', strtotime($crow['fecha1']))=="01/01/1970"){
    echo "";
}else{
    print date('d/m/Y', strtotime($crow['fecha1'])); 
}
```

con eso pude resolver.
ahora si la persona no ingresa la fecha de salida me muestra en blanco, así el cliente sabe que esa persona no tiene fecha de salida, ósea que se puede ir en cualquier momento.

saludos a todos